# Using array in outputing data from database

Tags: php, database

> why do we have to use array if we have too much data outputing from our database what's the advantage of that in php

Comment: I don't understand your question. Use array instead of what? Objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean why using array instead of objects here's your answer. Using array instead of objects is cheaper and faster. For small quantities of data fetch from the database the difference is minimal and a lof of people prefer working with objects than array.

But for large amount of data fetched array might be a good solution especially if you encounter memory or time issues.